# Using GroupBy and SelectMany in unison

Tags: c#, linq

I've been wrestling with this problem for a few hours now and I'm beginning to think I'm too far down the rabbit hole. Before I give up entirely, I'm hoping someone might be able to shed some light on this for me...

```
public class Object
{
    public Object()
    {
        Properties = new List<Property>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public IList<Property> Properties { get; set; }
}

public class Property
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public dynamic Value { get; set; }
}

    [Test]
    public void ShouldBeAbleToGroupAnArrayOfObjectsByASpecificProperty()
    {
        // Arrange
        var objects = new List<Object>();
        var doorObject = new Object() {
                                 Properties = new List<Property>() {new Property() {Name = "Level", Value = "Level 1"}}
                             };

        var wallobject = new Object() {
                                 Properties = new List<Property>() { new Property() { Name = "Level", Value = "Level 2" } }
                             };

        var chairObject = new Object() {
                                  Properties = new List<Property>() { new Property() { Name = "Level", Value = "Level 2" } }
                              };

        objects.Add(doorObject);
        objects.Add(wallobject);
        objects.Add(chairObject);

        // Act
        var groupBy = objects.SelectMany(obj => obj.Properties).GroupBy(props => props.Value);

        // Assert
        Assert.That(groupBy.Count(), Is.EqualTo(2));
    }
```

This test passes, but the problem is that I'm returning an array of Properties. I'm attempting to get an array of Objects. Is what I'm trying to do possible?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you're trying to group the objects by their "Level" property - what would you want to happen if there is an object with multiple differently-valued properties?

Comment: @tzaman - I'm not quite sure I understand the question? Properties can certainly have different values. In the example above I would like to have an end result with: a grouped set of objects all grouped by the "Value" of their Properties collection. I'm not really concerned about a negative test case at the moment. Does that help?

Comment: If it has different values in that collection, which group is an object supposed to go into? i.e. if a fooObject has say both "Level 1" and "Level 2" in its property set, should it be in two groups?

Comment: Ah, I see what you're saying. The property set wouldn't be allowed to have multiple properties of the same name. The object structure I've presented above doesn't reflect that business logic, but it's certainly an edge case I'll test for just to make sure it can't get in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
objects.GroupBy(obj => obj.Properties.First().Value);
```

or

```
objects.GroupBy(obj => obj.Properties.First(p => p.Name == "Level").Value);
```

Comment: Andrew, I can't thank you enough, sir. I've been beating my head against the keyboard for three hours and can't believe I didn't notice that. So simple. Thank you so much.

Comment: Is this really the right solution? As i understand it, you want to group objects together based on A matching property. In this solution you match for the first property.

Comment: I'm not giving it the correct solution just yet, because I'm going to put it to the test in the morning. However, the second option looks for the first property named "Level." Ultimately, that is what I want to be grouped by.

Answer (score 1):

Given what I now understand about your use case, I'd suggest just using `Dictionary` to store your property set, instead of a list of a custom class. It's the natural fit, since you just need name:value pairs, and you only want one value for each name.

Assuming you go with `var Properties = new Dictionary<string, dynamic>()`, this should do your grouping for you (given a property name):

```
var groupBy = objects.GroupBy(obj => obj.Properties['Level']);
```

This assumes that every object in `objects` has a value for `'Level'` in its properties, though.

Comment: To be honest, this is exactly what I'm going to change to. I'm going to attempt to implement a PropertyCollection that inherits from KeyedCollection<string, Property> in hopes that it provides a simpler interface for adding items to the Dictionary. Thanks for kicking my light bulb.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a query that gives you a combination of each object with its properties in a net enumerable. This makes it easy to navigate over and perform your group by.

```
var stretched = objects.SelectMany(x => x.Properties, (x, property) => new
{
    Object = x,
    Property = property
});

var q = stretched.GroupBy(x => x.Property.Value, x => x.Object);
```

Comment: I'll certainly give this a shot as well. Thanks, Polity.

Answer (score 0):

it would be better if you want to show what u want to achieve?
e.g.

```
    `Object A - property 1 {Name = "a"}, 2 {Name = "b"}, 3 {Name = "a"}`
    `Object B - property 1 {Name = "a"}, 2 {Name = "b"}, 3 {Name = "a"}`

How do you want to group
    object A - property.Name = "a", values - 1, 3
               property.Name = "b", values - 2
    object B - property.Name = "a", values - 1, 3
               property.Name = "b", values - 2
```

or

```
property.Name = "a", values - 1, 3 (objectA), 1, 3 (object B)
property.Name = "b", values - 2 (objectA), 2 (object B)
```

or

```
 property.Name = "a", a dictionary A (key - object A, values - 1, 3), a dictionary B (key - object B, values - 1, 3)
    property.Name = "b", a dictionary A (key - object A, values - 2), a dictionary B (key - object B, values - 2)
```